# get the scan input records size from spark UI

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to parse some data from spark UI by using rest api from this [doc][1]. the main thing that I'm try to get is 'scan input records size' but there are other thing as 'shuffle read size'. for doing that i check the syntax that written in this doc `http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/[app-id]/sql` but Im getting this msg:

> unknown app local-1619521159740, attempt sql

for compering if I type `http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/[app-id]/stages`
I'm getting the right result. dues anyone can help?
[1]: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Comment: What Spark version are you running? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27142 is resolved in 3.1

Comment: yes, I'm using 3.0 version. thanks